# Azure API backend service URL

Tags: azure, api, backend, azure-api-management, azure-policy

In Azure API management , how to change the backend service base url for each operations in single azure api instances

i tried

operation 1 [dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZAuN.png)

operation 2 [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaPz3.png)

operation 1 and operation 2 are under same azure API

and i got error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN8s9.png)

any one have ideas/suggestions

Comment: Hi, 404 error means the endpoint is not available. Go to the APIM trace (you can find that in Test section) and check what backend URL is called and if it is correct

Comment: Actually i want to change the relative path of my backend url . for ex  my backend url is https://azure.websites.net/api/dev then for operation 2 (refer my original post) i should change the backend url as https://azure.websites.net/api/qa

Comment: Even i tried with <rewrite-uri template="/qa" /> but it is appending in the backend url as https://azure.websites.net/api/dev/qa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure APIM "rewrite-uri" policy - How to remove the URL suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314693/azure-apim-rewrite-uri-policy-how-to-remove-the-url-suffix)

Comment: You can refer to [Set backend service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService), [Rewrite URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL) and [Azure API Management "rewrite-uri"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263679/azure-api-management-rewrite-uri)

Comment: Thanks @DeepDave-MT i went through the links i used set backend service and rewrite uri to achieve my need

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i used below template

[policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaQqJ.png)

so the backend service url changed to https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/dev